# Autocapitalize not working properly

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, input

Basically I have two text fields on my page, I am setting autocapitalize=true for first text-field and autocapitalize="none" for second text-field. It works fine when user clicks outside the text-field and then clicks on text-field. However it is not working when click on first text-field and then clicks on second field.

What happens

1) When focus is on text-field whose autocapitalize is true and if user click on text-field whose autocapitalize is 'none', same keyboard remains open. and again if user click on text-field whose autocapitalize is true, small letters keyboard gets opened.

Any help would be appreciated

```
<input type="text" autocapitalize="true" />
<input type="text" autocapitalize="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its `autocapitalize="on"` not `True` or this can help you [more](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/autocapitalize).

Comment: No luck with this